# Cannot install gem with rbenv

Tags: ruby, rubygems, openshift

I am trying to install Ruby 2.1.0 on Openshift Online(DIY cartridge) using rbenv. However, after compiled and installed ruby, I can't install new gem.

I've tried many gems such as `gem install rack -V` but the server stuck there with no error output.

At first, I thought maybe because the permission of gem directory so I change `GEM_HOME` to a writable directory, but the problem still persists.

If you know where the problem can be, please let me know.

Also this is the output of `gem env`:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.0
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.0 (2013-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/openshift/AUTO_GEN_HASH/app-root/data/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /var/lib/openshift/AUTO_GEN_HASH/app-root/data/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /var/lib/openshift/AUTO_GEN_HASH/app-root/data/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /var/lib/openshift/AUTO_GEN_HASH/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/openshift/AUTO_GEN_HASH/app-root/data/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
     - /var/lib/openshift/AUTO_GEN_HASH/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /var/lib/openshift/AUTO_GEN_HASH/app-root/data/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/bin
     - /var/lib/openshift/AUTO_GEN_HASH/app-root/data/.rbenv/libexec
     - /var/lib/openshift/AUTO_GEN_HASH/app-root/data/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-gemset/bin
     - /var/lib/openshift/AUTO_GEN_HASH/app-root/data/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin
     - /var/lib/openshift/AUTO_GEN_HASH/app-root/data/.rbenv/shims
     - /var/lib/openshift/AUTO_GEN_HASH/app-root/data/.rbenv/bin
     -
     - /bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /usr/sbin
```

And output of `which gem`

```
/var/lib/openshift/AUTO_GEN_HASH/app-root/data/.rbenv/shims/gem
```

`gem list` output:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.3)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
psych (2.0.2)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.0)
test-unit (2.1.0.0)
```

Debug result when running: `gem install rack --backtrace --debug -V`

```
Exception `Errno::EACCES' at /var/lib/openshift/AUTO_GEN_HASH/app-root/data/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/resolv.rb:654 - Permission denied - bind(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 10371
```

Comment: provide output of `which gem`.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ I've add output of `which gem`. Do you have any clue?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ I've added `gem list`

Comment: try:`gem install rack -V --trace`

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ I think the problem is because Openshift doesn't allow to bind to a port.

Comment: which port it doesn't allow to bind? local?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ I've just read the document of Openshift. Turn out that they do not allow to bind to 0.0.0.0, I must bind to an environment variable called $OPENSHIFT_INTERNAL_IP. Do you know how to config `gem` to work with this?

Comment: you can to bind the by `eth0` ip, it not not localhost, i.e. 0.0.0.0. anyway, I don't see the tie between the bind, and the gem install,. which is the source of your gems host?

Answer (score 0):

Openshift Online doesn't allow applications (or anythign really) to bind to localhost / 0.0.0.0 so change that to use the environment variable $OPENSHIFT_RUBY_IP and you should be all set.